# C programming: How to use sscanf with a ':' delimiter?

Tags: c, scanf

I have been trying to extract hours, seconds and minutes from an input text using `sscanf`.  After `sscanf` function is performed, only `s` variable which holds the seconds has the right value.  `h` and `m` which have hours and minutes in them hold only zeros.  Please suggest changes to my code below.

```
     char text[20];
     if (fgets(text, sizeof text, stdin)!= NULL){
         char* newline = strchr(text, '\n');
         if (newline != NULL){
             *newline = '\0';
         }
     }
     uint8_t s = 0;
     uint8_t m = 0;
     uint8_t h = 0;
     sscanf(text, "%02i:%02i:%02i",&h,&m,&s);
```

Note in the debugger, text has the right values.

Comment: can we see how you declare and initialize h,m and s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char hhmmss[] = "10:32:54";
    int hh, mm, ss;
    if (sscanf(hhmmss, "%i:%i:%i", &hh, &mm, &ss) != 3)
        printf("Failed to scan 3 values from '%s'\n", hhmmss);
    else
        printf("From <<%s>> hh = %d, mm = %d, ss = %d\n", hhmmss, hh, mm, ss);
    return 0;
}
```

gives this output:

```
From <<10:32:54>> hh = 10, mm = 32, ss = 54
```

The `%02i` conversions should also work, but the digits are somewhat superfluous.

---

The amended question shows that the variables are of type `uint8_t`, in which case you must use the correct conversion specifiers from `<inttypes.h>`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char hhmmss[] = "10:32:54";
    uint8_t s;
    uint8_t m;
    uint8_t h;

    if (sscanf(hhmmss, "%02" SCNi8 ":%02" SCNi8 ":%02" SCNi8, &h, &m, &s) != 3)
        printf("Failed to scan 3 values from '%s'\n", hhmmss);
    else
        printf("From <<%s>> h = %d, m = %d, s = %d\n", hhmmss, h, m, s);
    return 0;
}
```

This produces the same output as before.  With any of the `scanf()` family of functions, it is crucial that your format conversion specifiers match the types of the pointers you are passing into the function.  You can get away with quite a lot of mismatches in `printf()` - certainly by comparison - because of default integer (in particular) promotions, but `scanf()` is a lot less forgiving.

Answer (score 1):

@Jonathan Leffler's answer is entirely correct, but...

You should **never** use `scanf` or `fscanf` or `sscanf` for parsing input from file handle or a string, except perhaps in known-to-be-thrown-away-tomorrow code.  They are too error-prone and too hard to control.  For an exhaustive summary of the various problems with `scanf`, I recommend [this series of articles](http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-59.html).  A few highlights:

- If you need to read single characters, use `getchar`.
- If you want to read a string, `scanf` has all the buffer overflow problems of `gets`.
- If you want to read numbers, `scanf`'s parsing is error-prone and hard to use.  Use `strtoul` and `strtod` instead.
- If you have more complicated input, everything is just worse.

What to do?

- Read your own input using something better than `gets`, that is, without buffer overflow problems.  Do not attempt to combine getting the bytes in with interpreting them.
- Use a combination of `strcspn`, `strspn`, and `stroul` and `strtod` combined with some custom code to scan the input.

There are times when this too is a drag, but by that time your typically building some sort of input language that needs more generic techniques anyway.

Comment: I'd rather use `sscanf()` than `strtok()`.  At the least, `strtok()` is poisonous in anything like a library function.  You have to know that the called library function uses it, and ensure that nothing else in your code is using it at the same time.  Evil!  (Where available, `strtok_r()` is a lot safer and saner; it is at least usable, though it still has some issues.)

Comment: Yeah, I don't care for strtok either and would probably never actually use it, but its problems are orthogonal, in some ways, to the scanf issues.  That said, I've deleted the reference.